# Knockout.js bindings not updated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to populate a table after retrieving data from my API.

Relevant HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: places">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: clientName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: address1"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: address2"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: city"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: county"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: country"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: dateAdded"></td>
    </tr>         
</tbody>
```

js:

```
function Place(data) {
this.clientName = ko.observable(data.ClientName);
this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
this.address1 = ko.observable(data.Address1);
this.address2 = ko.observable(data.Address2);
this.city = ko.observable(data.City);
this.county = ko.observable(data.County);
this.country = ko.observable(data.Country);
this.dateAdded = ko.observable(data.DateAdded);
}

function PlaceListViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.places = ko.observableArray([]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SubscriberDashboard/SearchPlaces",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { "SearchTerm": "" },
    success: function (data) {
        var temp = [];
        $.each(data.places, function (placeData) {
            temp.push(new Place(placeData));
        });
        self.places(temp);
        console.log(self.places());
    }
});

}

ko.applyBindings(new PlaceListViewModel());
```

The data is loaded fine, the console.log at the end of the ajax call shows an array of Place objects. Equally, the appropriate number of `<tr>` elements are rendered, but there is no text in the `<td>` elements.

Edit:

```
function PlaceListViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.places = ko.observableArray([]);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SubscriberDashboard/SearchPlaces",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { "SearchTerm": "" },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.places, function (placeData) {
            self.places.push(new Place(placeData));
        });
        console.log(self.places());
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Do you mean the self.places(temp) call?  I added and edit to the question with new code (that still doesn't work)

Comment: My apologies guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing index to the `Place Model` not actual data. The first parameter for `$.each function` is `index`, the second parameter is `element`.

**$.each()**  Function( Integer index, Element element ).

Also it is good to have `var self = this` for each sub model you have to avoid conflict.

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/94/

```
$.each(data, function (index , placeData) {
   self.places.push(new Place(placeData));
});
```